# Inconsistent layout_weight in simulator vs Android Studio renderer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-weight

Below see the XML code and a screenshot.
Summary:

- One parent LinearLayout with `weightSum` = 100
- One child  LinearLayout with `layout_weight` = 25
- One child  LinearLayout with `layout_weight` = 75

Result:

- In Android Studio layout renderer the children ratio is OK (25:75)
- In the simulator the ratio between the children is **not OK** (clearly not 25:75)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:weightSum="100">

      <LinearLayout
          android:background="@color/md_orange_600"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="25"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_separator"
          android:background="@color/md_green_400"
          android:layout_weight="75">
      </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

[image: resulting screenshot]

Some notes:

- The `layout_height` is 0dp on both children (as it is recommended for weights)
- I colored the background so the area assignment is visible

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried it not only with 50:50, other ratios as well, and always the orange `LinearLayout` is smaller than it is supposed to be

Comment: I think some part of your layout is behind toolbar then.Try giving top margin

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, it looks that way. But it not supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root problem:

It turns out my main activiy layout has a `CoordinatorLayout` as a primary container.

`CoordinatorLayout` does children placement like `FrameLayout`, therefore my `AppBarLayout` and the main fragment container (`FrameLayout`) overlapped.
I just enclosed them both into a vertical oriented `LinearLayout` and now they don't overlap.

Corollary, my 2 cents for developers out there: It is tempting to bypass problems without understanding their real cause (I could have just add `layout_marginTop` on my fragment to "shift it down") but in the end, bypass after bypass you end up understanding less and less of your own application. Always look to understand the real cause of the problem you experience, then the solution will be real too.